# Have been having this error, ParserError: Expected ';' but got '}'

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, remix, private-blockchain

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract will {
    address owner;
    uint fortune;
    bool deceased;


    constructor() payable public {
        owner = msg.sender; //msg sender represent address that is begin calles
        fortune = msg.value;// msg value tell us much ether begin sent
        deceased =false;
          
    }
     
     //create modifier so that only person that can call the contract is the owner
        modifier onlyOwner {
         require (msg.sender == owner);
         _;
     }
    
 
    //create modifier so that only allocate fund if friends gramp deceased
        modifier mustBeDeceased {
         require (deceased ==true );
         _;
     }
    address payable [] familyWallets;


    //map tru inhertance
    mapping(address => uint) inheritance;

    //set inhertance for each address

    function setInheritance(address payable wallet, uint amount) public {
        //to add wallet to the family wallet .push

        familyWallets.push(wallet);
        inheritance[wallet] = amount;
    }

    //pay eeach family member besed on their wallet address
    function payout() private mustBeDeceased {
        //with a for loop you can loop through thing and set conditions
        for( i=0; i<familyWallets.length; i++ ) {
            familyWallets[i].transfer(inheritance[familyWallets[i]])
        }
    }
        
        //orcale switch simulation
    function deceased() public onlyOwner {
        isDeceased = true;
        payout();
    }     

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contract had multiple issues which made it impossible to compile. Here is a version that doesn't throw any errors. The first issue (`;` required) was for the `familyWallets[i].transfer` line.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Will {
    address owner;
    uint fortune;
    bool deceased;


    constructor() payable {
        owner = msg.sender; //msg sender represent address that is begin calles
        fortune = msg.value;// msg value tell us much ether begin sent
        deceased =false;
          
    }
     
     //create modifier so that only person that can call the contract is the owner
        modifier onlyOwner {
         require (msg.sender == owner);
         _;
     }
    
 
    //create modifier so that only allocate fund if friends gramp deceased
        modifier mustBeDeceased {
         require (deceased ==true );
         _;
     }
    address payable [] familyWallets;


    //map tru inhertance
    mapping(address => uint) inheritance;

    //set inhertance for each address

    function setInheritance(address payable wallet, uint amount) public {
        //to add wallet to the family wallet .push

        familyWallets.push(wallet);
        inheritance[wallet] = amount;
    }

    //pay eeach family member besed on their wallet address
    function payout() private mustBeDeceased {
        //with a for loop you can loop through thing and set conditions
        for(uint256 i=0; i<familyWallets.length; i++ ) {
            familyWallets[i].transfer(inheritance[familyWallets[i]]);
        }
    }
        
        //orcale switch simulation
    function declareDeceased() public onlyOwner {
        deceased = true;
        payout();
    }     

}
```